# content copy protection in wordpress

Tags: plugins

I would like to know, is there any plugin wich can protect my page's text content which is located "Developer tools"  in browsers. I use "WP Content Copy Protection & No Right Click" plugin, but it can't protect my text content wich is located in "Developers tools" in browsers.[image]

Comment: If its visible on the page, you can get it. You could use membership plugins to block content for specific roles, but if you know how, you will never have a problem copying a page. Best way is to block content behind a pay wall, but even then, that user can copy and publish the content as his own (its illegal sure but it can happen).

Comment: Nothing can prevent the developer tools doing that, and pages can be loaded without a browser at all, e.g. via command line, AJAX, etc. Users can also turn off javascript to defeat your protections, drag and drop, etc. All you're doing is making your site less accessible and more difficult to use. E.g. without right click I can't ask my computer to speak the text out loud, or lookup a word I don't recognise. I could also just tap to select on a touch device, or select text then press ctrl+c to copy

Comment: thank you for your answers...

Comment: you can at least provide few security, you can block ctr+shft+i which opens the dev tool in the console and you can follow this same approach on another browser too. This will give you at least some kind of security and also can block right-click, Use this approach only if it's necessary and yes Tom J is right